# "Consider me in", about the phrase and its negation

Tags: phrases, negation

I have wanted to ask about the proper negation of the phrase "Consider me in", but as I have found nearly no result when I searched it on Google, I need to know first if it is common and correct. *I'm sure I have come across it multiple times.*

An example  (*written by me*):

> Well, if that's the case, then **consider me in**.

I found only [this sentence](https://ludwig.guru/s/consider+me+in) with the phrase, but **in** is written between double quotes, which raises the question "why"? (It is the first sentence on the website)

---

About the second part of my question -if the phrase happened to be a normal, correct phrase- Is its proper negation "Don't consider me in" or "Consider me out"?

As in this example (*written by me*):

> Unless you want to talk about computers, **consider me out**.

---

I assume "consider me in" means "consider me included in that particular activity".

Comment: I bet I know the answer, but can you tell us what the phrase "consider me in" means to you?

Comment: Sure. I've added that.

Comment: Free beer at your house? Count me in! If belonging to your group of friends means I have to be a vegan - count me out! Consider is too elevated and scholarly for casual use.

Comment: I've certainly heard people use it casually. The same sort of people who use less common vocabulary casually, of course, but people - and native speakers.

Comment: As an American (southern states) I would consider "consider me in" somewhat more formal than "count me in". But I would not classify it as elevated.  "I would deem it a kindness if you would include me in the aforementioned grouping." Now that's elevated. 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would consider "consider me in", and "consider me out", idiomatic. They're just not as usual in written material as the more common "I'm in" and "I'm out", or indeed "count me in" or "count me out". They are, however, an idiomatic variation of the same thing.

Literally, *consider me X* doesn't mean *I am X*, it means that the person you are saying it to should think of you as *X*, regardless of whether you are or not. Perhaps you aren't yet - "I would like you to consider me your friend" - or you're stepping into someone's shoes - "for the next week, consider me your boss" - or you want them to assume it for the time being, but you reserve the right to change your mind, as might be the case if you say "consider me interested". Perhaps there's some of that in this case, a slightly less firm statement than "I'm in".

In any case, either *consider me in* or *I'm in* means that you and indicating that you want to be included in whatever is being discussed.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. Does the **in** between quoted marks, that is mentioned on the website I've attached, indicate something?

Comment: @TasneemZh That's basically stylistic, to make sure that you don't treat *in*, when reading it, as a preposition. It's not necessary, but it's to make sure it's read in the same way you intend. It's unlikely to be read otherwise, though. They might just be worried about people saying "consider you in *what*?", as that could be not the end of the sentence - it could have been truncated from, say, "consider me in charge". That's not a real risk, unless you talk to a lot of grammar pedants.

Comment: For my machine, your link provided nothing in quotation marks, nor anything in any way relevant… why, I have no faint idea.

"Consider me X" does mean "Count me as X". Whether you really are or not means nothing, and nor does that other stuff…

Answer (score 1):

I’ve never encountered *consider me in*, but I was able to figure out the meaning which, I suppose, is close to

> count me in
>
> I am in
>
> include me
>
> take me into account

I am sure *count me out* exists, but I have no idea if *consider me out* correct and idiomatic.

Comment: Andrew Tobilko - "I am sure count me out exists" But when you talk about destruction/Don't you know that you can count me out - the Beatles _Revolution_

Comment: Thank you for stating the possible meanings since I can use them as alternatives. By the way, it appeared to be correct and idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this sentence from web:

> The game comes out on February the 28th, exclusive to PlayStation 4. Consider me in.

The above sentence lets us think that in this case, "Consider me in" have the same value as "count me in".